# Playwright, how to leave iframe? Or why my elements are not visible

Tags: playwright

my question is "How to get an access to other elements which are outside the iframe".\

```
        const frame = this.page.frame({name: "messagecontframe"});
        await expect(frame.locator(this.confirmationMessage)).toBeVisible();
        const bookingID = await frame.locator("(//td[@class='v1right'])[1]").innerText();
        await frame.locator(this.cancelBookingButton).click();
```

after that actions I need to navigate to another URL and do something on another page, but I simply can't even click something, all elements are not visible for me. I believe that's because "I'm still in iframe". How to solve that problem? Is there something like iframe.leave ?

Comment: Not tried. But check this frame.goto(url[, options])

Comment: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator might help a lot for dealing with iframes